# Can ffmpeg be used to output to bytes

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am using c#.

is it possible to output to a byte array rather than a file at all when using ffmpeg?

I am using the process method to execute ffmpeg.

Thanks

Comment: -i \"" + Filename + "\" -vf \"scale=640:-1\" -an -vframes 100 -r 1 -f image2pipe - Check this out:- http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply and thanks for the link.  I have looked but i am unsure how i can use this in my process method within c#.  You wouldn't have any further pointers please?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. You gotta learn how to use the other [protocols](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html) FFmpeg has. Input/output to a file is just a particular protocol... but you can output, for example, to a socket, to a FTP/HTTP, and so on...

It's very easy for anyone to create a new protocol (in C, of course) and register it with FFmpeg. I don't think FFmpeg has a built-in solution to write to a buffer, but for sure it's possible. I've done this once.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reconfirmation. i will read more closely about protocols. Thanks